# MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException in selenium, python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an Accounts Menu. When we place mouse over it, its sub menu's appear on the screen.
The Screenshot is as below.

[image]

I want to click on Accounts Summary.My selenium code is as following.

```
def test_accounts(self):
    self.login(self.driver,properties.userid,properties.password)

    element_to_hover=self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Accounts')
    hover=ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover)
    hover.click().perform()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Account Summary').click()
```

I get the following error.

```
    test_accounts (__main__.TestCase) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: test_accounts (__main__.TestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\New Workspace\Python Test\src\login.py", line 78, in test_accounts
    self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Account Summary').click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 51, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 225, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 160, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 149, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: '' 

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 24.563s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I tried a lot of links in SO and others but was unable to find a solution for my problem.
Since I am a newbie to Selenium, is this the **correct way** to **mouse over** a link and go to its hidden sub elements?

I am using python 2.7.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This is the way you should click on the element:

```
accounts_button = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Accounts')

hidden_button = browser.find_element_by_id(hidden_button)

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(accounts_button).click(hidden_button).perform()
```

So as you could see, that's it and please remove the last two lines of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the succession of the events should be:
move to element Accounts -> move to element Account summary -> click element -> perform